# How to Fix My 1D Array to a Functional 2D Array (Homework Help)

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to turn a 1D array into a 2D array, but I'm not sure how to fix my *for* loops to get it to compile and print correctly. I've changed my declared variables so that the numbers inputted are going into the array, but perhaps I'm not loading them in correctly? Or perhaps what I'm asking in my *for* loop is incorrect?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
      System.out.println("Ashanti's Assignment");
    int[][] numbers = new int[0][7];
    int[][] digits = new int[0][7];
    int[][] count = new int[0][7];
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;      
  
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("Enter seven numbers: ");
  
  for(i=0;i<7;i++)
      numbers = new int [0][7];
  
  for(i=0;i<7;i++)
  {
      for (j=0;j<7;j++)
      {
          if (numbers[i]==numbers[j])
          {
              digits[i]=numbers[i];
             }
      }
  }
 System.out.println("The integers selected and their counts");
 
 for(i=0;i<7;i++)
     System.out.println("Number " + digits[i] + " occurs " 
             + count[i] + " times");   
}
```

}

I've looked through another post here, but it's not helping me understand what to do.

Comment: Your _numbers_ array is of length _0_.  `numbers = new int[0][7]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck right at the very start.

You have written, `int[][] numbers = new int[0][7];` which says create a multi dimensional array with 0 elements.

Let's remove the complexity of the multi-dimensions for a second.  Start with a normal array.  Yours would look like this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[0];
```

We have created an array with 0 elements.  Because of this, we can't add any data to the array.

When creating an array, you need to know upfront how many elements you want in your array.

E.g. if you want 7 elements:

```
int[] numbers = new int[7];
```

Next, you can add back in the complexity of the multi-dimensional array.  How many elements do you want in the 2nd dimension?  Also 7?  Or something else?  Let's say you only want 2 elements in the second dimension.

```
int[][] numbers = new int[7][2];
```

Does this make sense?

The next problem you have is:

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
      numbers = new int [0][7];
```

For each loop, (e.g. 7 times), you are creating a new multi-dimensional array and assigning it to `numbers`.  You don't need to do this because you already initialsed the `numbers` variable above.  I can't offer any advice here because I don't know what you intended to do here.

Comment: Additionally, you can use a _jagged array_, which has no 2nd dimension length.

Comment: This helps a bunch. Thank you, I figured I needed to declare something else within the array, but I forgot it was the elements.

Answer (score 0):

On the initial run of your code, I get the following error.

```
Ashanti's Assignment
Enter seven numbers: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at Example.main(Example.java:26)
```

Line 26 is

```java
if (numbers[i]==numbers[j])
```

The *numbers* declaration is using a 1st-dimension size of 0.
So, there are no available indices, when accessing *i* and *j* on line 26.

```java
int[][] numbers = new int[0][7];
```

It appears that you only need a single dimensional array for the task—instead of a 2-dimensional array.

The syntax for a single dimensional array is as follows.

```java
int[] numbers = new int[7];
```

Additionally, you'll need to capture the values from the *Scanner* object.

```java
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Ashanti's Assignment");
    int[] numbers = new int[7];
    int[] digits = new int[7];
    int[] count = new int[7];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter seven numbers: ");

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            if (numbers[i]==numbers[j])
            {
                digits[i]=numbers[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The integers selected and their counts");

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        System.out.println("Number " + digits[i] + " occurs "
            + count[i] + " times");
}
```

Here is an example input and output.

```
Ashanti's Assignment
Enter seven numbers: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
The integers selected and their counts
Number 1 occurs 0 times
Number 2 occurs 0 times
Number 3 occurs 0 times
Number 4 occurs 0 times
Number 5 occurs 0 times
Number 6 occurs 0 times
Number 7 occurs 0 times
```